# WPF Hidden Application and MainWindowHandle

Tags: c#, wpf, webforms

I have a WPF application that starts as a normal. The user can then hide the application. When they hide the application it no longer shows on the Taskbar and the main window is hidden by calling Hide().

At some point in the future the user starts another application that should Show the first app. I have tried to show the first app with the following code:

```
        private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL =1; 

        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName);

        int nProcessID = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            if (nProcessID != p.Id)
            {
                p.Refresh();
                ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

                SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
            }
        }
```

However this doesn't work because the MainWindowHandle is always zero. I understand that this is because the app is no longer visible in the taskbar and therefore no longer has a handle.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: interprocess communication